# rails pg_search: which model attribute contained the search term?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, pg-search

Fairly simple question that I hope has a simple answer:

I'm using pg_search scopes in a rails app: https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#pg_search_scope

How do I know *which* columns on my model contained the relevant search terms? Assume I'm searching against `:headline` and `:expertise` columns on a user model and I want to know whether it's the `:headline` or `:expertise` column that was successfully hit by pg_search for a query such as "Ruby on Rails"?

In my User model:

include PgSearch

```
  pg_search_scope :search,
    against: [:headline, :expertise],
```

Thanks!